# Store word in 32-bit MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, bit, addressing

I have a doubt about the store word instruction in 32-bit MIPS assembly. Assuming that I have this in the data section:

```
.data
vector: .word 2,3,4,5,6......
```

and that the vector in memory starts from address 10 (decimal base example). When I do:

```
.text
 sw $t0,vector($t1)
```

is the label `vector` is replaced with 10?

EDIT:

```
li $v0, 1 
la $a0,vector 
syscall
```

I did so and I saw the start address but I don't understand a thing: if the immediate field is 16-bit and the label is replaced with the start address of `vector`, with 16 bit how do I address all memory?

Comment: You can find out by looking at the output from the assembler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the address manually. MIPS doesn't have load effective address instruction (LEA) like x86

```
la $t1, vector
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

If the absolute address value fits within 16 bits, you can use absolute addressing

```
sw $t0, vector($zero)
```

If $t1 contains the address to the data segment then use this

```
sw $t0, vector($t1)
```

I don't know the assembler's syntax so you may need to specify something to get the offset of absolute address

Comment: I don't understand: in your second example (sw $t0,vector($zero)) 'vector' is replace with the address of start vector in memory?(for example 0x000000e)

Comment: it's the absolute address of vector, which is the start of vector in memory

Answer (score 0):

The assembler is helping you out behind the scenes. The register number 1, aka. `$at` is reserved as *assembler temporary* (hence the name). If the address doesn't fit into the available bits, the assembler will generate extra instructions that calculate the full address using `$at`. You can see that if you disassemble the resulting object file:

```
   0:   3c010000        lui     at,0x0
                        0: R_MIPS_HI16  .data
   4:   00290821        addu    at,at,t1
   8:   ac280000        sw      t0,0(at)
                        8: R_MIPS_LO16  .data
```

After linking, the above snippet may look like this:

```
  400000:       3c010040        lui at,0x40
  400004:       00290821        addu    at,at,t1
  400008:       ac28100c        sw  t0,4108(at)
```

The address of `vector` has been split into the low and high 16 bit halves with separate relocations. First, the `lui` will load the high 16 bits into `$at`. Then the value of `$t1` is added. Finally, the low 16 bits of `vector` are encoded in the `sw` instruction itself.